# UIWebView HTML is displayed as text

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want to display some HTML content inside a `UIWebView`.
The problem is that the response is being displayed as plain text and HTML is not rendered at all.

```
@IBOutlet weak var related: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        related.delegate = self

        related.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://kida.al/api/related_iOS.php?video_name=uhbaby")!))
}
```

This is what I get inside `UIWebView`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you own this server? Looks like the page content isn't being sent properly.
The HTML is not rendered when you hit that URL in a web browser either:

[image]

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

I used to output JSON form my web app but when I changed it to output HTML for my iOS app forgot to remove that.....

Comment: one small question.. Where do we put the CSS? Inline?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. `UIWebView` is a full-featured web browser framework. You can inline it or put it in a separate file. Up to you.

Comment: by the way I'm using `WKWebView` not `UIWebView`

Comment: Not sure about your HTML tags. Doesn't matter if you're using `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`. Generally if you open up Safari on your mobile phone and visit the page, `WKWebView` will render it the same way within your app.